# Search through a file with multiple searches and remove matches in the file

Tags: powershell, foreach, select-string

I have a text file containing a single column of IMEIs (file1.txt).  I have a second file containing a single column of IMEIs (file2.txt).

What I'm trying to do is take each IMEI in file2.txt and search through file1.txt locating any matches and then when it finds a match, remove that line in file1.txt.

What's making it difficult is the multiple searches I need to perform at once.  Doing each one at a time would take quite a while as there are hundreds of IMEIs in each file.

Does anyone have any suggestions to accomplish this task?

Script:

```
$orders = Get-Content c:\file2.txt
foreach ($order in $orders) {
    Get-Content file1.txt | Select-String -Pattern "$order" -NotMatch
}
```

The above works but because I'm searching a couple hundred "matches", it returns the "not matches" every time so it's returning thousands of results.

Comment: can you add what you've tried so far

Comment: What is the size of `file2.txt`? If it will fit in memory, it should be easy enough to create a hash from it, then read `file1.txt` and omit those contained in the hash. Please edit the question and paste in the code and any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `compare-object` here.

```
$file1 = (1234,5678,9123)
$file2 = (1234)

$remove = Compare-Object $file1 $file2
$remove = $remove | Where{$_.SideIndicator -ne '=>'}
$file1 = $remove.inputobject
```

That will remove what is equal and only give back what is in the first file, removing all like IMEI's. You can then just export it with `Out-File` and overwrite your previous file.

Comment: @dlemley no problem! Happy to help.